# Is there a regex expression to remove text between tags containing a specific word

Tags: regex, xml, pcre, conditional-formatting

I have made a regex expression to remove text between `<FormattingRule` and `</FormattingRule>`

Now i also want to include a extra condition: It must contains EdtJobEmpId.

Can someone assist me with this?

I have tried to following regex expression:

`<FormattingRule(.|\n)*?<\/FormattingRule>`

It can be found on the site : https://regex101.com/r/ttUMON/1

I want to remove the following text based on the extra condition:

```
        <FormattingRule Action="OnChange">
            <Triggers>
                <Trigger PropertyName="${EdtJobEmpId}" />
            </Triggers>
            <Choose>
                <When Condition="${EdtJobSkcId}==Empty">
                    <Assign PropertyName="${EdtJobSkcId.Value}" Value="=${EdtEmpSkcId.Value}" />
                </When>
            </Choose>
        </FormattingRule>
```

Comment: You might try using a xml parser instead.

Comment: So like is `EdtJobEmpId` contained in a value of a attribute/value inside of a tag, or is it free floating inside or outside a tag ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way it is done.
If you think you will run into problems where your html/xml has
constructs that could hide markup like *Comments or CDATA* (or anything else)
and you are worried about it, let me know and I'll patch up this
regex with a couple of functions to consume those bad boys.

`(?:<(?:(FormattingRule)(?:\s+(?>"[\S\s]*?"|'[\S\s]*?'|(?:(?!/>)[^>])?)+)?\s*>)(?:(?!</\1\s*>)[\S\s])*?EdtJobEmpId(?:[\S\s]*?</\1\s*>|(*SKIP)(*FAIL)))`

https://regex101.com/r/Plih3R/1

Readable version

```
 (?:
      <
      (?:
           (                             # (1 start), End tag req'd
                FormattingRule
           )                             # (1 end)
           (?:
                \s+ 
                (?>
                     " [\S\s]*? "
                  |  ' [\S\s]*? '
                  |  (?:
                          (?! /> )
                          [^>] 
                     )?
                )+
           )?
           \s* >
      )
      (?:
           (?! </ \1 \s* > )
           [\S\s] 
      )*?
      EdtJobEmpId
      (?:
           [\S\s]*? </ \1 \s* >
        |  
           (*SKIP)(*FAIL)
      )
 )
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no regular expression that will get this 100% right every time. For example, most attempts will be defeated by such things as comments, CDATA sections, and entity or character references in the source.

The right tool for this job is XSLT.

Comment: I can see how _**Comments**_ and _**CDATA**_ could hide markup. Can you tell me what / how _sections_ could hide markup. And also, things that have no internal mechanism's to _hide_ markup are stuff like DOCTYPE, ATTLIST, ENTITY, ELEMENT, etc .. So, maybe you could explain ? Obviously, I could write the _anti-defeat_ mechanized regex, but I would like to here what you say .

Comment: Sorry, typo, there should have been no comma between "CDATA" and "sections"

Answer (score 1):

This regex matches `<FormattingRule>` nodes only if they contain `EdtJobEmpId`:

```
(?m)<FormattingRule((?!/FormattingRule).)*EdtJobEmpId((?!/FormattingRule).)*\/FormattingRule>
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/uveGDSEEzCcsE4).

It works by used the "multi-line" flag `(?m)` and negative lookahead `(?!/FormattingRule)` to not match outside the currently matching tag.